How to see the graph of this? $n=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(z)+\sin(z)\cos(x)$
$$n \text{ (constant)} = \sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(z)+\sin(z)\cos(x)$$
Code is this, but I can't emulate this. Why?
Even WolframAlpha can't make graph too.
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D



def tetrahedral_function(x, y, z):

    return np.sin(x) * np.cos(y) + np.sin(y) * np.cos(z) + np.sin(z) * np.cos(x)


x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)

y = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)

z = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

f = tetrahedral_function(x, y, z)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=f, cmap='viridis', marker='.')

ax.set_title('Tetrahedral Function')

ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()


You're trying to plot it as a function and not as an isosurface. I believe plotly has tools for plotting isosurfaces. https://plotly.com/python/3d-isosurface-plots/

Apparently Desmos now how some 3d plotting capabilities.  Following the link will take you to this:

